# I would argue that VS I argue that

Tags: tense, modal-verbs

I googled the meaning of "I would argue that" and one site said:
a phrase used to introduce an argument:

> I would argue that Ferguson's courts **prevented** the justice system.

I also found these:

> However, I would argue that these benefits **are** outweighed by the drawbacks.
>
> In fact, I would argue that it **goes** against the values of a free and fair society to force a group of people to do something against their will.

In the first example , the tense after "I would argue that" was past but in the latter two , the tenses were present.

What is the difference between "I would argue that" and "I argue that"?

Can we bring any tense after "I would argue that"?

Answer (score 4):

> I would argue that it will certainly rain tomorrow.

is milder and less direct in tone than

> I argue that it will certainly rain tomorrow.

The form with "would" is a little more soft and polite. The speaker openly admits that he may not be 100% right about the issue.

Note that I used **will** in both my example sentences. The part starting with "that" is a [content clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_clause), and it can assume any tense, because its tense does not depend on **would**:

> I would argue [that it **will rain** tomorrow].
>   I would argue [that it **rained** yesterday].
>   I would argue [that it **rains** often in this city, because it is surrounded by mountains.]
>   I would argue [that it **would have rained** if we had been in my home city instead.]

---

The word whose tense directly depends on "would" is "argue". It can assume only the Present Simple form:

> I would **argue** (CORRECT)
>   I would **argued** (WRONG)

Comment: Thank you very much. Explained in detail but I have one question.

You said "it can assume any tense, because its tense does not depend on would".


Considering this , can we write something like "I would argue that it would rain tomorrow."?

Comment: @AntonioConte - yes

Comment: @AntonioConte - everything that comes after **that** is another clause. This clause has its own subject ("it") and its own verb phrase ("would rain"). It is not restrained by the presence of "would" in the main clause.

Comment: The clause after "argue" is not a relative clause. It's a content clause.